# How to Set SQLCommandTimeout in App.config

Tags: c#, sql

I have developed a Window Service using SQL Database currently in my DB is full of Record so query execuction taking much time while default command timeout is 30S but I want to increase it to 120S one option is

```
com.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

but I have many methods in my Application so I want to set it from APP.config file so it will be applicable for Application level, can anyone please tell me how could I achive this

Thanks

Comment: No such setting available that can be configure in app.config

Comment: Add a new command timeout setting under appSettings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add a new entry in `<appSettings>` something like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="commandTimeout" value="3000" />
</appSettings>
```

Afterwards, create a `CommandFactory` class that will populate the value

```
class CommandFactory
{
    public static int CommandTimeout
    {
        get
        {
            int commandTimeout = 0;
            var configValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["commandTimeout"];
            if(int.TryParse(configValue, out commandTimeout))
               return commandTimeout;
            return 120; 
        }
    }

    public static SqlCommand CreateCommand(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand()
        {
            Connection = connection,
            CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout
        };
        return command;
    }
}
```

Now, in your code, instead of just instantiating a new `SqlCommand` just call the `CommandFactory` method:

```
using(var command = CommandFactory.CreateCommand(yourConnection))
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this  in app.config file

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connectioStringName" value="Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=tableName;User Id=databaseName;Password=password;Connection Timeout=3000"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This will set the `ConnectionTimeout` property of the `SqlConnection` not the command timeout. See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx